# TYPO3 7.6 realURL tx_news Tags configuration

Tags: tags, typo3, realurl, tx-news

I use `TYPO3 7.6.6` with `news 4.2.1` and `realURL 2.0.14`.
I'm using the realURL-Config from the [official news-documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html), see below.

I have one detail page for my News (id=33) and my news-tags are listed in folder id=32

```
...
'fixedPostVars' => array (
  ...
  '33' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
  '14' => 'newsTagConfiguration' // must be the list view for news records
  ...
```

The links from the news-list to detail page are working perfect (`http://www.example.com/profi-guides/news/detail/some-text/`), but I also show the tags, and if the user click, I've got a link like this:

```
http://www.example.com/news/detail/?tx_news_pi1%5BoverwriteDemand%5D%5Btags%5D=11&cHash=40c263fd16c0e3a3c548c952f1d6b1da
```

This is my FLUID-Snippet in the News-List-View:

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.tags}">
                    <!-- Tags -->
                    <div class="tags">
                        <i class="icon-icon-tag"></i>
                        <f:for each="{newsItem.tags}" as="tag">
                            <f:link.page title="{tag.title}" class="active" pageUid="{settings.listPid}" additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{tags: tag}}}">
                                <span>{tag.title}</span>
                            </f:link.page>
                        </f:for>
                    </div>
                </f:if>
```

How do I get clean realURL-Links from news tags?

**My Goal:** Listview of news records. If the user click a tag below every news-record -> list view show all news with the corresponding tag. This works already. Only the Link/Querystring is the problem, I need nice URLs, and nothing like `..?tx_news_pi1%5BoverwriteDemand%5D%5Btags%5D=11&cHash=40c263fd16c0e3a3c548c952f1‌​d6b`

My news-list plugin is at `uid14`, the detail-view at `uid33`, my news records at `uid31`and my news tags at `uid33`.

**The solution:** realURL Config : `newsTagConfiguration`has to be the uid from list view, not from the folder, where the tags are included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point to show each news with the tag, so you have a small misconfiguration because of your folder ID.

The documentation says:

> "The configuration of newsDetailConfiguration is used for the single
>   view. Its name is not that important but the same name has to be used
>   in line 86 where the uid of the single view page is set. In this
>   example it is 70. Of course you need to set the uid of your single
>   view page."

I think the solution is simple, you need a single view to your tags just like for the categories and not the folder, where your records are collected.

You can not open a tag inside a folder but you need a page with a plugin to handle that.

See the "Tag List" in the documentation from news [here.](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/UsersManual/Plugins/Index.html#tag-list)

> Tag list
>
> Use this action to show a list of tags.
>
> If you define a specific page id in field "PageId for list display"
>   (inside the tab "Additional") and placing a news plugin with the type
>   "List" there, it is possible to create a tag filter.

UPDATED from the comments:

Try to change the ID to your news List page ID. You have a page for list it is X you have a detail it is 33 and a Folder it is 32. So you have to change 32 to X. See your fluid you have there a part in the link.page: pageUid="{settings.listPid}" listPid is the value, what needed to be used for the Taglist config as well.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I have some problems to understand it, sorry. I use the single view `uid14` there are my news records and I show the tags below every news record. So I have also my detail page ùid33` - and now I also need another detail view for my tags? New plugin `tags`, but how can I link to that page?

Comment: What is your goal? What should happen if a user clicked on a tag? Should he view all news in this tag?

Comment: Listview of news records. If the user click a tag below every news-record -> list view show all news with the corresponding tag. This works already. Only the Link/Querystring is the problem, I need nice URLs, an nothing like `?tx_news_pi1%5BoverwriteDemand%5D%5Btags%5D=11&cHash=40c263fd16c0e3a3c548c952f1d6b`

Comment: Try to change the ID to your news List page ID. You have a page for list it is X you have a detail it is 33 and a Folder it is 32. So you have to change 32 to X. See your fluid you have there a part in the link.page:
 pageUid="{settings.listPid}"
listPid is the value, what needed to be used for the Taglist config as well.

Comment: Hi András, I think, I've got it. I changed the realURL-config to `... '14' => 'newsTagConfiguration' ...` , so `uid14` is my X, the list view. I've post an image at the initial post, to show on:hover tags see status bar ... thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am happy that my answer could help you find a solution :)